# XML data retrieval

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have saved the XML files as Variant data type.The XML contains

1. complex types
2. Hierarchy up to 6 levels
3. The complex attributes within has multiple occurrence

I need to read the values, attributes of all the complex types in the XML.

Does there any way to read all the complex attributes and values within Snowflake?

What should be the best way to read such XML's stored in Snowflake i.e. JAVA, Python etc?

Below is the sample XML for the scenario:

```
<?XML VERSION="1.0" ENCODING="UTF-8"?>
<DEPT NAME='ACCOUNT'>
    <EMPLOYEE CITY_NAME='CALIFORNIA'>
       <EMPNO>8888</EMPNO>
       <ENAME>QUEEN</ENAME>
       <JOB>ELIZABETH</JOB>
       <DEPTNO>10</DEPTNO>
       <SAL>5000</SAL>
       <SKILLS YEAR='2017'>
            <UI>AngularJS</UI>
            <MW>JAVA</MW>
            <DB>MYSQL</DB>
       </SKILLS>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE CITY_NAME='AUSTIN'>
       <EMPNO>7777</EMPNO>
       <ENAME>KING</ENAME>
       <JOB>PRESIDENT</JOB>
       <DEPTNO>10</DEPTNO>
       <SAL>5000</SAL>
       <SKILLS YEAR='2018'>
           <SKILL>
                <UI>AngularJS</UI>
                <MW>.Net</MW>
                <DB>ORACLE</DB>
            </SKILL>
            <SKILL>
                <UI>HTML</UI>
                <MW>JAVA</MW>
                <DB>Hive</DB>
            </SKILL>
       </SKILLS>
    </EMPLOYEE>
</DEPT>
```

Need to retrieve all the employees and skill details. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you read through the Snowflake documentation?  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-semistructured.html.  I would start there.  Also note that the XML functions are Private Preview, which means not production, yet.  Also, you should be able to do this completely within Snowflake.  No need for JAVA or Python.

Comment: Check out the examples in this blog post as well: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Easily-Load-XML-with-SQL-Pt-2 the operators SELECT XMLGET(src_xml, 'SKILLS', 0):$ FROM stored_xml; though you may actually want to combine the XMLGet and Lateral Flatten for the example you provided.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have achieved the same in via Get and GetXML functions.